# FosElasticaBundle Dynamic Index?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I'm building a multi-tenant application with multiple indexes, one index per tenant.

Just wondering if there has been any work on allowing the index names to be changed **dynamically**?

Comment: I don't think, `FOSElasticaBundle` will let you do that since it needs mapping configuration in order to do things like hydration. But still you can use pure `Elastica` library. Or.. if you'll develop something on your own, let us know! ;-)

Comment: you can create by codding in your application each tenant target single unique index

Comment: Did you finally figure out some way to do it ?
I'm dealing with the same problem in multi-tenancy right now.